# Docker dynamic expose port via host mode, but the ports are not accessible from external

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network, frp

I'm trying to run a [frp](https://github.com/fatedier/frp) in a container, which needs to listen on dynamic ports. That means the frp may open additional ports in running time.

## My operations step by step

1. On my remote VPS, I use the following command to start a frp server. Note that I use `host` mode which means, by Docker doc, that all the opened port of frp is accessible from host and external machines.

```
docker run -d \
--network=host \
-v /etc/frp:/etc/frp/:ro \
--name frps \
--rm \
290007431/frps:v0
```

Here is the program inside the container, which shows that port 7500 and 9000 is available [image: beginning].

2. On my Mac (Big Sur) and Raspberry Pi (Debian 10), I try to visit the dashboard web via port 7500, which results a failure. So I use `namp` to scan the port. Here is the result [image: result]. It shows that the 7500 and 9000 are unaccessible from the client endpoint (Mac and Raspberry Pi).
3. As things goes out of my mind, I return back to my VPS to check whether the port is actually exposed or not. I use `netstat -nlptu` command, here is the result which shows that the VPS is listening on 7500 and 9000 port[image: result].

**Isn't it very odd?**

Comment: Host networking doesn't work on MacOS, and is usually unnecessary.  You should be able to use the `docker run -p` option to publish (and, if needed, remap) ports out of containers.  When you try to call the container, what URL are you calling, from where, and what results do you get?  (Please add these details to the question is text, not images: screen shots of terminals can be hard to read and impossible to search later.)

Comment: Thank you for watching question, I have reorder the question to make it more clear. And I am still trying to find out the reason. Are there some suggestions? @David Maze

Comment: Thanks @hannele for your grammar instructing.!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!! I found the reason why I can not access my VPS from external. That is the VPS Provider has the default firewall, which run outside of the VPS.
I login into the VPS Provider console and configure it. What a foolish story